# Setting cursor priority with AIR native cursors

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to set the priority ([`CursorManagerPriority.HIGH`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManagerPriority.html)) of a mouse cursor set via `Mouse.cursor = '...';`?

Long story short, I've had to resort to using the [`CursorManager`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html) to apply cursors, because setting the priority is crucial for my application due to the HTML control overriding all cursor changes without a high priority. Setting cursors with the cursor manager totally works, but the cursors aren't as fast/response as those rendered at the OS level (as described [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/03/native-cursors-in-air-2-6.html)).

If there isn't a way, my next question is: is there any way to suppress the cursor changes made by the [HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) control? Setting `mouseEnabled = false` does it... but disables all mouse events on the HTML page, so that doesn't work.

---

**Example:**

This doesn't work:

```
setInterval(function():void { Mouse.cursor = 'ibeam'; }, 100);
```

Setting a cursor with a high priority works, however:

```
// ibeamCursor is an embedded PNG
CursorManager.setCursor(ibeamCursor, CursorManagerPriority.HIGH, -2, -4);
```

(this code is used at `mx:Application` scope)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have access to the code for the HTML control...otherwise, I'm not sure you can do this at all.

I don't think you can set priority on cursors set by Mouse.cursor = "..."; (tho I could be wrong...if anyone has info to the contrary, feel free to correct me.)

However, I think you can very easily suppress cursor changes simply by using a boolean variable and an if-statement.

```
var customCursors:Boolean;
```

Then, on each place where the cursor changes occur...

```
if(customCursors == true)
{
    Mouse.cursor = "mycursor";
}
```

This will allow or suppress changes to the cursors, simply by changing the customCursors variable.

However, there may be something more useful if you're dealing with two conflicting cursors, and you want one to only take place during certain instances. For that, you could try a different if statement.

In my own code, I want one cursor to show up only while dragging an object, but not just while the mouse is over it. One is inside the move event, and the other inside the over event. There was a third that would show up only when the object was dragged over a certain point, and when it was not, it needed to be the regular dragging cursor.

This created a rather annoying conflict...

To fix that, **I actually checked the Mouse.cursor property in my if statement!** The placement of various Mouse.cursor statements in my events created a sort of priority for the cursors. It works perfectly.

In my mouse over statement:

```
Mouse.cursor = "hand";
```

In my mouse down statement (where I start dragging):

```
Mouse.cursor = "dragging";
```

In my move statement:

```
if(Mouse.cursor == "draggingover")
{
    Mouse.cursor = "dragging";
}
```

In my mouse up statement (where I stop dragging):

```
Mouse.cursor = "hand";
```

In my mouse out statement:

```
Mouse.cursor = "pointer";
```

I hope this helps! If it does, don't worry about overlooking this seemingly obvious solution...I think we're all prone to do so when we're looking for built-in functions.

If this isn't helpful, sorry. Again, I don't think there is another way, but if anyone knows of one, please weigh in.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it! I've been known to overlook the obvious :) The main problem is that setting `Mouse.cursor` doesn't reliably override the mouse cursor set internally by the `HTML` control. Because of this, I'm stuck using `CursorManager` which makes the cursors feel really slow because they're not native.

Comment: Does the HTML control have access to the same document root as whereever you're calling CursorManager from? What method is the HTML control using to set the cursor?

Comment: I have no idea what the HTML control is using to set the cursor... that's somewhere buried in the Flex SDK / webkit. As for the question about the document root... I'm not really sure how this is relevant because I'm setting the cursor from outside the control (not via JS in the page within the HTML control, which could lead to some security exceptions).

Comment: In that case, hm, I really don't know. I'll keep digging, and if I find anything, I'll post it.

Comment: Can you post a bit of code from where you're trying to change the cursor?

Comment: Just added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: This could be blatantly obvious but, on the former method, you remembered to register the cursor and all that fun stuff? Because, frankly, Mouse.cursor should override everything, regardless.

Comment: `'ibeam'` is the same thing as `MouseCursor.IBEAM` (which is provided by the SDK)... so there's nothing that needs registered. It's a mystery...

Comment: Weird thought...try that again with a custom cursor. Maybe there's something odd with the built-in or something...

Answer (score 0):

I believe HTML control inherits from [ScrollControlBase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html).  Try fixing your Mouse issues on that parent control, rather than on the HTML control.

Also, you can try overriding the HTML control, adding code to remove default cursor look and feel.  See [this blog post](http://artandlogic.blogspot.com/2007/08/getting-back-hand-cursor-in-as3.html), and just do the opposite.

Comment: It's not `ScrollControlBase` or my code to blame for the janky cursors; Flex's implementation of Webkit is just very sketchy. For instance, put your cursor over a link inside the control, and it flickers to the hand cursor... then goes back to the arrow cursor a few milliseconds later. As for overriding the HTML control: it's not a basic button where setting `buttonMode` / `useHandCursor` will work.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Maybe you can add the tags "javascript" and "Webkit" to get better advice.

Comment: Try [a CSS fix](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp):  `html{ cursor: inherit; }`.  (Sorry that I cannot test this code right now.)